# Temporal Tables: Replace system generated date column with your own column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

How might I use my own columns for `PeriodStart` and `PeriodEnd`? I want to insert old data into the table; and I would like the period start and period end to not reflect the day that I inserted the row, but the date it was generated in its source.

Consider this small table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TemporalExample
(   [ID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL   
  , [Surname] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL  
  , [Salary] INT NOT NULL  
  , [PeriodStart] datetime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START  
  , [PeriodEnd] datetime2 (2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END  
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (PeriodStart, PeriodEnd)  
 )    
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.TemporalExample_HistoryTable));
```

If I have two columns, `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate` -- how can I have these columns act as the `PeriodStart` and `PeriodEnd`? If I swap them out, it will either tell me:
(1) that the column names are the same, or (2) the system time does not match the always generated items and that they are required.

I am using Azure SQL Server if it matters.

Comment: You cannot do this; SQL Server only supports system-versioned temporal tables, and what you want is manually versioned temporal tables. This is one of the big restrictions of the implementation today, unfortunately. You can insert rows with custom time, but this requires turning off system versioning, inserting the rows into the history table, then turning it back on -- this is quite involved and doing it for every insert can have negative consequences for performance, so this should usually be reserved for incidental loading of historical data.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!